# Upload an Image from camera or gallery in my WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have done on app convert my website to app with webview
i want to Upload an Image from camera or gallery
i want to add to for example if i want to share on facebook it need to open facebook app or if i click links it need to ask me to go outside
what should i change or add?
Thank you!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView();
}

//Metodo llamar el webview
private void webView() {
    //Habilitar JavaScript (Videos youtube)
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //Handling Page Navigation
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    //Load a URL on WebView
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.nehmen-geben.com/");
}

// Metodo Navigating web page history
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

## AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "WebClientListener" and override the "shouldOverrideUrlLoading".

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClientListener());
```

and `private class WebClientListener extends WebViewClient {
 //other callback......
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    //Intercept the url you specified in this method.
    //e.g. Define a specified url like "http://yourhost.com/shareToFacebook" 
    //in your html and when you cathch this url, use the facebook's sdk to share,
    //and return "true" to tell the webview to handle such url yourself.
    //
    //If you want to open the browser outside,you can use:
    //Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    //startActivity(intent);

    }
}`

If you just want to upload the file like photo in webview, you can try

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

override the `onShowFileChooser`(after lollipop) and `openFileChooser`(prelolipop) of the interface.